# Openstack instances cannot access Internet [linuxbridge]

Tags: bridge, openstack, openstack-neutron

I am having serious issues in the deployment of the Openstack scenario related to the Linux Bridge.
This is the scenario:

**Controller** machine:

- Management Interface `enp2s0`: 138.100.10.25.

**Compute** machine:

- Management Interface `enp2s0`: 138.100.10.26.
- Provider Interface `enp0s20f0u4`: 138.100.10.27.

Openstack Train scenario has been successfully deployed in Centos 8, choosing networking option 2 (self-service network).

To verify the functionality, an image has been uploaded, created an Openstack flavor and security group, and launched a couple of cirrOS instances for connection testing.
We have created a provider network following [this tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-rdo/launch-instance-networks-provider.html) and a selfservice network following [this one](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-rdo/launch-instance-networks-selfservice.html).

The network scenario is the next one:

[Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOOB4.png)

As can be seen in the network topology, an external network 138.100.10.0/21 (provider) and an internal network 192.168.1.1 (selfservice) have been created, connected through a router by the interfaces 138.100.10.198 and 192.168.1.1, both active.

Our problem is that our Linux bridge is not working as expected: the Openstack cirrOS instances has no internet access.

This is the controller `ip a` and `brctl show` command output:

[Modena_ip_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCnVe.png)

This is the compute `ip a` and `brctl show` command output:

[Testarossa_ip_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIwqs.png)
[Testarossa_brctl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P896K.png)

(The output of `ovs-vsctl show` command is empty in both machines).

**Are the Linux Bridges correctly created?**

These are the Linux bridge configuration files:

- Controller `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini`:

```
[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = provider:enp2s0   # enp2s0 is the interface associated to 138.100.10.25

[vxlan]
enable_vxlan = true
local_ip = 138.100.10.25    # controller has only 1 IP
l2_population = true
```

- Compute `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/linuxbridge_agent.ini`:

```
[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = provider:enp0s20f0u4      # interface associated to 138.100.10.26

[vxlan]

enable_vxlan = true
local_ip = 138.100.10.27
l2_population = true
```

An **observation** to keep in mind is that compute management interface (`138.100.10.26`) is inaccessible from anywhere, which I think is not correct since this prevents us, for example, from accessing the instance console through the URL.

I have made some conection tests and these are the results:

- Cirros_a `ip a` command output:

[Cirros_a_ip_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJEdy.png)

- Cirros_b `ip a` command output:

[Cirros_b_ip_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmWA4.png)

- There is **connection** between Cirros A and Cirros B (in both directions).
- There is **connection** between Cirros A/B and self-service gateway (192.168.1.1) (in both directions).
- There is **connection** between Cirros A/B and provider gateway (138.100.10.198) (in both directions).
- There is **connection** between Cirros A/B and controller management interface (138.100.10.25) (in both directions).
- There is **no connection** between Cirros A/B and compute management interface (138.100.10.26). This interface is not accessible.
- There is **connection** between Cirros A/B and compute provider interface (138.100.10.27) (in both directions).

I do not know if there is a problem on linux bridge configuration files, or maybe I need another network interface on controller machine.

Comment: One observation: You use the Newton tutorial, although Newton is not supported anymore. Train may require different settings. If I were you, I would restart from scratch and follow the Train instructions.

Comment: Now, your instances are able to access the compute node's provider interface and the controller. This means they have access to the network outside of the cloud. How did you test internet access? Can the controller and the compute node access the internet?

Comment: Another oddity, although I don't think it has anything to do with your problem: Why do the instances have two interfaces, one being connected to the provider network? What is the purpose of this configuration?

Comment: @berndbausch What do you mean with I use the Newton tutorial? I use the last Train tutorial from Openstack page: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/openstack-services.html#minimal-deployment-for-train.

Comment: @berndbausch Yes, they can access the computer's provider interface and the controller's management interface. I test internet access inside the machine (I can ssh the instance from controller or compute instance). Yes, both computer and controller has access to Internet.

Comment: @berndbausch The instances have two interfaces just for testing purposes. In a first approach I launched them with only one interface, and I wanted to discover which was the difference.